# Get previous existing MySQL row in Zend 1

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

my problem's connected with getting the next existing id in my DB.
While finding the next element works pretty good:

```
$this->view->next = $images->fetchRow($images->select()->where('id > ?', $imageId));
```

I can't find the previous element:

```
$this->view->prev = $images->fetchRow($images->select()->where('max(id) < ?', $imageId));
```

I always get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function
```

Could you help me with solving this problem?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you are misusing the max clause since it can't be in the where clause but in the select.

The easiest way to do this would be with subselects, i.e.:

```
$select = $images->select(true)
                 ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
                 ->columns(array(
                     'MAX(id)'
                 ))->where('id < ?', $imageid);

$this->view->prev = $images->fetchRow(
                                $images->select()
                                ->where('id = ?', $select);
```

This will generate a clause like:

```
SELECT `tablename`.* FROM `tablename` WHERE (id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `tablename` WHERE (id < 17)));
```

But I think that the best way is not to use a subselect nor the MAX clause, but the order and the limit. You will order all the row results of your query in descending order by id and then select just the first one:

```
$this->view->prev = $images->fetchRow(
                                $images->select()
                                ->where('id < ?', $imageid)
                                ->order('id DESC')
                                ->limit(1);
```

This will generate:

```
SELECT 
    `tablename`.* 
FROM 
    `tablename`
WHERE
    (id < 17)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Which will give you the same row.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, this actually works and is the most suitable solution :)

Comment: If that, could you, please, mark it as correct, please? ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write an ***AGGREGATE function(MAX)*** in **WHERE clause** which is not allowed in the MySQL database. You need to put your condition to **HAVING() clause** in order to solve the error(Invalid use of group function) you are getting.

Try doing something like:

```
$this->view->prev = $images -> fetchRow($images -> select()
                                                -> group('id')
                                                -> having('MAX(id) < ?', $id)
                                                -> order("id DESC") );
```